# How to add references to images in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, bibliographies

I need to add references to some images included in my beamer presentation (via `pgfuseimage`) as these images are not mine but taken from some other sources. Which ways are there to do this, what would be the best practice?

Of course I can try to manually add footnotes or manually put some `\cite` commands near the images. But I'd like to have a better solution that gives consistency throughout the presentation. And that preferably allows for later tweaking of the appearance, e.g. changing from references in the footnote to references in captions etc.

Are there way to do this or packages that might help? The references would need to show up on the very frame the image is used, not in some bibliography list at the end of the talk.

Comment: If you want flexibility I would define your own command using `\newcommand` which calls the actual formatting command. If you later decide you want a different format you just have to change own definition, not every usage.

Answer (score 1):

use the caption format without printing the label:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}% only for demo
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelformat=empty,
            justification=raggedright,
%            singlelinecheck=false
  ]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{tiger}
\caption{This image belongs to foo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```